# iTunes 12.5.4: generic icons in "artists" view sidebar?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes 12.5.4, I have mostly generic icons in the "artists' view. This is a huge waste of vertical height and I wish I could turn off these icons  – but since I can't, does anyone understand how these icons are populated with image data? I have a few icons with images but did nothing (knowingly) to accomplish that.

(sorry the image is so huge)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this but changing things like the Sort Artist and Album Artist seems to change things for me. If I do that, I get picture Icons. My guess is that in order for iTunes to contact its database of artist images, it needs detailed information to avoid errors.